# How can I make a detailed view with express?

Tags: javascript, express

I’m **working on the detailed view**, but I do not have a very clear idea of how to make these routes.

I want to copy the same behavior that yarn has when selecting a package, regarding routing.

[image]

Comment: Explain what you want, show us what you got.

Comment: I'm just starting the project, I just want to know how that behavior can be achieved.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve